# SharePoint Online List Item Attachment downloading instead of opening in Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, item-attachment

When accessing SharePoint Online list item attachment, in Internet Explorer, the file (*.docx) is being opened with O365 login. But in Chrome browser the file is directly downloaded to local computer.

So in IE, when we open the attachment and make edits and save it, file is directly updated for list item. But in Chrome, we have it downloaded to local computer and hence edits will not be carried over to actual attachment file.

Is there a way to default open the attachment with O365 login similar to IE browser?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in both IE and Chrome and the list attachment files are opened in browser by default. See a related document here: [A SharePoint Online list item attachment doesn't open in the Office client application as expected.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/office-app-fails-opening-list-item-attachmentOpen)

Can you reproduce this scenario when you open a document from a library? If yes, your Chrome might have been set to not open docx files in client application.

Consider giving Chrome a reset or test on another machine to see the result.

Comment: Document library list items are opening in browser. Only the custom list item attachments are getting downloaded in Chrome instead of opening in browser O365 apps. For example, attachment URL in the form will be like below.

https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso/Lists/ListName/Attachments/ItemID/Test.docx

When this URL is opened in IE, it opens the file prompts for login and all changes are saved to O365 directly. 

But the same URL if opened in Chrome browser, file gets downloaded to local computer directly and doesn't prompt login.